# specify .so files in build.gradle file android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, build.gradle, .so

This is my Directory Structure

```
src -main

    -java

    -jniLibs

            -armeabi

                     -lib1.so
                     -lib2.so
```

***Need to understand what piece of code should be written in build gradle file for these files to be included in the build.
Right now, i am getting the error of not finding the .so file.***

```
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libFPEComponent.so"
```

Following [solution by H.Brooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44932104/4075178)

I have got to add here

[image]

[My Git repository:](https://github.com/vikas0/BiometricRecordSample)

My bUild.gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    productFlavors {
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
            }
        }

    }

    sourceSets
            {
                main
                        {

                            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jnilibs']

                        }

//Another code

            }

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.goambee.biometricziqitza"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    splits {

        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {

            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true

            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

            // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
            reset()

            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "armeabi-v7a"

            // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')


    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}

//task native-libstiveLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
//    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
//    baseName 'native-libs'
//    from fileTree(dir: 'src/main/jnilibs', include: '**/*.so')
//    into 'lib/'
//}
//
//tasks.withType(JavaCompile)
//        {
//            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
//        }
```

**Here i have included source set block, i also had tested without that block.**
**So still build isn't able to access .so files.**

Comment: Are you trying to build a library or do you want to run the .so files directly in your app?

Comment: Use those .so files

Comment: If you use .so files you don't have to do anything in gradle.. you can use it directly from the folder

Comment: Did you use android NDK to build the .so files?

Comment: Well, i haven't written any code in build.gradle and as i have shown the structure, those .so files are in src/main/jniLibs, but it doesn't work, as it fails with the error "unable to find some.so file".  What should i do?

Comment: Did you use android NDK to build the .so files?

Comment: @H.Brooks, I was provided those .so files from samsung guys with other files such as sdk to integrate biometric    dara.

Comment: Android Studio has 'Analyze APK' menu. Check that libFPEComponent.so can be found there.

Comment: no, i could not find it, but there is a .h file generated.

Comment: I was searching for some git project with the use of .so files in the project, didn't find one yet.
Can you guys share such link?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it you can call it in your class like this:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libSONAME");
}
```

Add the following in your `gradle`:

```
jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
```

---

**Edit:**

Adding .so Library in Android Studio

1. Create Folder "jniLibs" inside "src/main/"
2. Put all your .so libraries inside "src/main/jniLibs" folder
3. Folder structure looks like,
   |--app:
   |--|--src:
   |--|--|--main
   |--|--|--|--jniLibs
   |--|--|--|--|--armeabi
   |--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
   |--|--|--|--|--x86
   |--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
4. No extra code requires just sync your project and run your
   application.

**Reference**

https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle/tree/master/src/main

---

Not sure what files you exactly have, if you only have .so?

---

**Have a look at the image below:**

[image: structure]

**This is a 'project/library' within my project and this is how the load the .so files get loaded/added:**

[image: loading library]

I compile the project like this:

```
compile project(':videokit')
```

Comment: Not likely. The error message suggests that loadLibrary failed, not that the native methods could not be resolved

Comment: @H.Brooks, when this code runs.i have put it as a method in My MainActivity, still gives the same error.

Comment: @H.Brooks, exception is caught at the line  -'catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.out.println("UnsatisfiedLinkError in static block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }'

Comment: Can you please show me how you are trying to implement and use the .so files?

Comment: how can i do that, should i edit the original question and add images, or is there a way to send images in comment.

Comment: Yes update your original question and include the file names, image of where you have put then and your gradle at the moment.

Comment: @H.Brooks, Edited, also included the git repository.

Comment: You are not running it on a emulator?